# php 403 error creating form and send text value of url

Tags: php

i want to create form in php and when i put value of a input text like "http://qwe.com/qwe.mp4" and when i click submit. it will redirect to 403 error.
this is my code.

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>title: </td><td><input type="text" name="title"></td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan=2 align=center>Video Link</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Low: </td><td><input type="text" name="llow"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Medium: </td><td><input type="text" name="lmed"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>High: </td><td><input type="text" name="lhigh"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></td><td><input type="reset" name="reset"     value="Reset"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want to submit on the same page then why not `PHP_SELF`?

Comment: i already try it. there are no error if i use wamp. but when i use hostinger the error will appear

Answer (score 0):

If you want send an error:

```
 if( !empty( $_POST[ 'submit' ] ) ) {
   header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 403 Forbidden', true, 403);
   exit;
 }
```

Put this at the beginning and then you have after every POST an 403 error.

Comment: where i can put that?

Comment: i forgot the exit and changed the message